# Adding items to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Admit it. Being new to JavaScript in 2018 is difficult. Coming from languages like C#, Java and Typescript(yeah subset of js..) where type safety is key, Javascript just keep f***** me over. I struggle with something simple like updating an array..

So I have this `React` component, where the state is defined like this:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      shoes: []
    };
  }
....
...
}
```

The shoes is an array of undefined(?)

This array is passed to a stateless component which looks like this

```
const Shoelist = props => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {props.shoes.map((shoe, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <Shoe shoe={shoe} />
          <Separator />
        </div>
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

I in my `Form` component, I have a method which is supposed to react(doh) on `onClick` methods. In this method I get a parameter with a new shoe to add in this list. This is very it stops for me in javascript - something which is faaaaairly easy in all other languages that we've being using for the past years..

I've tried several ways:

**1#**

```
 addShoe(shoe) {
        this.setState(state => {
          const list = state.shoes.push(shoe);
          return {
            list
          };
        });
      }
```

This results in an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` Do I need to define shoes as an `Array`? I thought the `[]` was enough

**2#**

I googled, I do that alot. I found one blog post saying something about `react-addons-update`. I installed this by running `yarn add` and code looks like this:

```
addShoe(shoe) {
    this.setState(update(this.state, { shoes: { $push: [shoe] } }));
  }
```

which results in `Uncaught Error: update(): expected target of $push to be an array; got undefined.`

Help! How difficult can this be?

**EDIT**

I pass this method into another component like this:

```
<ShoeModal onClose={this.addShoe} />
```

in the ShoeModal component this is bound to a onClick method:

```
<FinishModalButton
          onClick={this.props.onClose.bind(this, this.state.shoe)}>
....
</FinishModalButton>

ShoeModal.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but an observation of something that might bite you later. `.push` doesn't return the array - it returns the count. So I think `const list = state.shoes.push(shoe);` won't give you what you expect later.

Comment: Can you show how `addShoe` is called?

Comment: I've updated the question. Please let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your updates we can see that the issue is the way the `addShoe` callback is passed. It's being invoked as a function instead of a method of an object, so it loses context.

Change it to:

```
<ShoeModal onClose={this.addShoe.bind(this)} />
```

or

```
<ShoeModal onClose={shoe => this.addShoe(shoe)} />
```

In addition, `.push` returns the count of the array, so the following line won't give you what you expect:

```
const list = state.shoes.push(shoe);
```

See @merko's answer for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
this.setState({
     shoes: [...this.state.shoes, newShoe]
})
```

`...` adds all elements from `this.state.shoes`

Comment: It's called [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, merko. But the result is: Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. Do I need to install any packages from yarn?

Comment: Could you console.log(this.state.shoes), seems like it's not an array or an object ?

Comment: Seems that you are correct. The output in chrome is: undefined

Comment: Where do you call the function ?

Comment: Here is the simple app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2svott Hope it helps, ask anything you need

Comment: Thanks! @merko a combination of this and onClose={this.addShoe.bind(this)} worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `addShoe` method is not an arrow function.
Using arrow functions because the context `this` is of the component.

Second, you are returning the object `{list}`. This sets the variable `list` in state. 
Also push to the new `list` variable instead of mutating state.
Change your function to

```
addShoe = (shoe) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      let list = state.shoes;
      list.push(shoe);
      return {
        shoes : list
      };
    });
  }
```

Comment: We don't know how he's calling `addShoe` yet. He could be doing it with an arrow function or `.bind`. The `addShoe` method on the class doesn't necessarily have to be an arrow function.

Comment: Doing it with a bind.

Comment: Ok now with the update we can say that the way the method is passed is a problem. `<ShoeModal onClose={this.addShoe} />` should probably be `<ShoeModal onClose={this.addShoe.bind(this)} />` or `<ShoeModal onClose={shoe => this.addShoe(shoe)} />`

Comment: @FrankModica magic! Can you post that as an answer and I'll accept it?